# What kind of the Content-Type will this request use?

Tags: c#, php, http-post

I trying to access data service through http request using C# HttpWebRequest.
When ContentType is x-www-form-urlencoded, it works.
But i need to transfer files in that request, so I used multipart/form-data and ran into 401 error from service. Looks like I need to somehow put files in x-www-form-urlencoded, but how?

I have working code in php. Can anyone explain, what ContenType it uses in generated request and, 
thereafter, how files are encoded?

```
<?php
function encode($str) {
  return iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8", $str);
}
function decode(&$resp) {
  if (is_array($resp)) {
    foreach ($resp as $key => $value) {
      if (is_string($value))
        $resp[$key] = iconv('UTF-8','WINDOWS-1251', $value);
      else 
        decode($value);
    }
  }
}

$url = "https://demo.krate.ru/api/v1/reports.json";
$api_key = "zzVAhVCj6rg1dAzAXo_c";

$request = array(
    'request[acceptance]' => '@d:/Users/RangerX/Downloads/YvFuRusNvwk.jpg',
    'request[passport_scan]' => '@d:/Users/RangerX/Downloads/YvFuRusNvwk.jpg',
    'request[reg_idx]' => '445000'
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "d:\\Dev\\Projects\\krate2_demo\\doc\\v1-api-client-example\\AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 200 && $status != 201 ) {
  die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
// chcp 65001
var_dump($response);
?>
```

Comment: It uses _all_ the content types!

Comment: Are you sure you want to tell the whole world your api key for that site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't transfer files within `x-www-form-urlencoded` - investigate why you are getting the response to authenticate yourself instead.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the content type doesn't mean the server will understand what you are sending automatically.

If you are also coding the endpoint you are communicating with check out the section of "[Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)" in the PHP manual.

Also check out [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/), it is an HTTP client that will enable you to create service clients or communicate with an API server with a few lines of code.